# Send XML attributes along with Elements via ajax to C# controller method and parse to save

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-attribute

Normally XML elements to get edited on web page are sent over as the input name
Example :

Then In C# controller method:

```
List<string> keys = Request.Form.Keys.Cast<string>().Where(item => item[0] == '/' && item[1] == '/').ToList();
foreach (var key in keys)
{
   var item = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(key, manager);
   if (item != null)
      item.InnerText = Request.Form[key];
   else
       throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not decode parameter with key " + key + " and value " + Request.Form[key]);
}
```

Normally the XML elements are sent over in a Request.Form part of a Key Collection, thus 1 key example is:

```
"//IVS-NONINST-REC/IVS-NONINST-REC-REST[1]/IVS-SEC-DIAG-CDS[1]/IVS-SEC-DIAG-T[1]"
```

However, there are Attributes that I need to send over to have those parsed over and saved as well.
I'm not sure how to send them over "properly" and if I send attribute over like

```
"//IVS-NONINST-REC/IVS-NONINST-REC-REST[1]/IVS-SEC-DIAG-CDS[1]/IVS-SEC-DIAG-T[1]/IVS-SEC-DIAG"
```

The code loop hits the throw new InvalidOperationException.

1. How can I properly send over the attributes?
2. How can I properly parse over the attributes in C# to save them?

The XML for that element and its attribute looks like this

```
<IVS-SEC-DIAG-T IVS-SEC-DIAG="C56.9" IVS-SEC-POA="">test</IVS-SEC-DIAG-T>
```

Update, complete xml (deleted some for brevity)

```
 <IVS-NONINST-REC xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <IVS-NONINST-REC-KEY IVS-REC-TYP="2" IVS-TM-STAMP="210549" IVS-ADJ-KEY="5">    
    </IVS-NONINST-REC-KEY>
    <IVS-NONINST-REC-REST IVS-PAT-ID="333089302">
      <IVS-SEC-DIAG-CDS>
       <IVS-SEC-DIAG-T IVS-SEC-DIAG="C56.9" IVS-SEC-POA="">test</IVS-SEC-DIAG-T>
    </IVS-NONINST-REC-REST>
</IVS-NONINST-REC>
```

While I can see all the xml elements and attributes in the xDoc InnerHTML,  the xDoc thinks there are no attributes  Here is a screencap

[image: screencap of xDoc]

Comment: I've read this a few times now, and I am not sure I fully understand. Let's start with this: 1) what exactly do you mean "send over"? 2)  What is "manager"? 3) Have you verified that in xDoc there IS an item that matches your key?

Comment: Send Over - from html with ajax.     For this attribute "IVS-SEC_DIAG" i'm just appending it to end after the element /IVS_SEC_DIAG-T[1]

Comment: Manager is     XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());      , I see that it does add a few namespaces  like  manager.AddNamespace("ns0", ".....

Comment: Yes - this IVS-SEC-DIAG" is a key that I added - but but sending XML data in request form to be parsed I'm not sure if the attributes should be added to the end ...

Comment: Have you tried `xDoc.SelectSingleNode(key)`?  The namespace isn't required.

Comment: And also, can you show us the complete XML Node that you are trying to find?

Comment: Ok, @CaseyCrookston  I added the snippet of xml to the bottom of the question ,   thx again

Comment: Have you studied this? Take a look, and if you still have trouble, come back and let me know. It looks like you are doing a few things wrong. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I'm trying to study it,  I added a screencap as well of the xDoc in VS studio watch

Comment: You should add `@` to attribute name in xpath. `"//.../IVS-SEC-DIAG-T[1]/@IVS-SEC-DIAG"`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  - YEP , that worked.   A co-worker pointed that out.   If you want to put up a quick answer, then I can properly credit you.   thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `@` to attribute name in xpath.

```
//.../IVS-SEC-DIAG-T[1]/@IVS-SEC-DIAG
```